How to check if Angular application running in cloud mode
I'm working on an Angular application and need to determine whether it's running in cloud or not. How can I check the mode programmatically within my Angular code? Are there specific Angular utilities or environment variables I should use to achieve this?
I’ve tried checking the environment files (environment.ts and environment.prod.ts) to see if there’s a variable indicating the environment mode but these file only let me see that whether i am in production or local mode.

What exactly do you mean by "the app is running"? If you need to check if the server provides the files, try to load a file from the server such as the index.html. In case you want to be notified when the application cannot be loaded on the client (i.e. due to runtime errors during startup): This is very hard to achieve, because in this case it can happen that none of your Angular code is even executed..

I want to add custom functionality in my Angular app based on the environment. Specifically, I want to implement different logic depending on whether the app runs in cloud mode or locally. For example, if the app runs in the cloud, I might want to enable certain features or configurations that differ from the local development setup.

If it's environment-dependent,, make environment.prod-local.ts and environment.prod-cloud.ts files and set a flag in each. Then import/read the environment as usual. Just make sure your cloud deployment serves with the --configuration=prod-cloud flag.

After a spending a lot of time on it, I have got this solution:
Create an environment file for cloud mode, e.g., src/environments/environment.cloud.ts:
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    isCloudMode: true
};

Modify angular.json: Add the cloud configuration to the build section:
"cloud": {
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.cloud.ts"
    }
  ]
}

Also, add the cloud configuration under the serve section, don't forget to add this otherwise you're gonna get this error: An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'cloud' is not set in the workspace.
"serve": {
  "configurations": {
    "cloud": {
      "buildTarget": "your-app-name:build:cloud"
    }
  }
}

Use the environment in your code:
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

console.log(environment.isCloudMode);

Run the app in cloud mode:
ng serve --configuration cloud or ng serve --c cloud

